# pass string as arguments with spaces to bash function

Tags: bash, function, arguments

I'm trying to pass a string to a function.  The string contains multiple arguments and some of the arguments may begin with multiple spaces.

```
#!/bin/bash
test_function() {
    echo "arg1 is: '$1'"
    echo "arg2 is: '$2'"
    echo "arg3 is: '$3'"
}

a_string="one two \"  string with spaces in front\""
result=$(test_function $a_string)
echo "$result"
```

Here is the output actually produced:

```
arg1 is: 'one'
arg2 is: 'two'
arg3 is: '"'
```

Here is an example of the output I am trying to achieve:

```
arg1 is: 'one'
arg2 is: 'two'
arg3 is: '  string with spaces in front'
```

How can I store arguments containing spaces in a string like this to later be passed to a function?

Although it can be done with an array, I need to first convert the string into the array values.

Answer (score 2):

[With an array.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

```
a_string=(one two "  string with spaces in front")
result=$(test_function "${a_string[@]}")
```

Comment: the problem is that i would need to first convert the string into the array values.  an_array=("$a_string") how can this be done?

Comment: You don't. You use an array to begin with.

Comment: easier said than done in the actual application.  it gets passed through multiple functions and manipulated along the way.

Comment: It requires a bit more work, but you can pass the name of the array as an argument, and use indirect access.  In some cases, simply passing the elements as positional parameters (with `$@`) works well, it is not an array but works similarly.

Answer (score 0):

`bash -c` may be what you're looking for (or perhaps even better, `eval`, as John Kugelman points out below). From the man page,

> If the -c option is present, then commands are read  from
> the  first  non-option argument command_string.  If there
> are arguments after the command_string, the  first  argument
> is  assigned  to $0 and any remaining arguments are
> assigned to the positional parameters.  The assignment to
> $0  sets  the name of the shell, which is used in warning
> and error messages.

Basically `bash -c "foo"` is the same (plus a subshell) as `foo`. In this way we can easily insert our string as arguments.

Here it is in your example:

```
#!/bin/bash
test_function() {
    echo "arg1 is: '$1'"
    echo "arg2 is: '$2'"
    echo "arg3 is: '$3'"
}

a_string="one two \"  string with spaces in front\""

export -f test_function
bash -c "test_function $a_string"
```

(The `export` is necessary in this example because it's a defined function, but wouldn't be in other cases).

Output:

```
arg1 is: 'one'
arg2 is: 'two'
arg3 is: '  string with spaces in front'
```

Comment: `eval` is simpler, and executes in the current shell rather than a subshell. I don't recommend it nor `bash -c`, though. Ignacio's advice to use an array is the way to go. One should simply never store multiple words in a string like this. No point in trying to unmangle mangled data; just avoid mangling it in the first place.